# How to rewrite a domain to s3 using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I read a lot about redirect and rewrite rules but I've not found a solution for my problem yet.

I have some files on aws s3 in a specific path:
https://yyy/Public/CD_VWR_REV_10.8_Nov2019/index.html

Then I have another domain https://example.com (linux)

I need a rule that does the following:

when a user calls https://example.com/docs/CD_VWR_REV_10.8_Nov2019/index.html, he must see the content of page https://yyy/Public/CD_VWR_REV_10.8_Nov2019/index.html, but he must see https://example.com/docs/CD_VWR_REV_10.8_Nov2019/index.html.

He must never see domain https://yyy

I tried this:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^docs/(.*)$ https://yyy/Public/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But it only redirect to new domain that become visible then

I tried this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^docs/(.*)$ https://yyy/Public/$1 [L,P]
ProxyPassReverse / https://yyy/
```

but I get 404

I can do the same thing using another server where I have IIS and proxy enabled. In this case I use this rule:

```
<rule name="test" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="docs/(.*)$" ignoreCase="true" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="https://yyy/Public/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

and everything works ok

Is this possible with htaccess?

Thanks

Comment: Where exactly are you using these directives? You state `.htaccess`, but if you used `ProxyPassReverse` in `.htaccess` then you'd get a 500 Error (not a 404)? Do you have access to the server config? Ideally, you need access to the server config in order to configure a "reverse proxy" - which is what you need here, it's not a _simple_ "rewrite".

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It's a simple linux hosting where I can work only on .htaccess file

Comment: If you are on a _shared_ server then mod_proxy may not even be available. (The `P` flag channels the request through mod_proxy -  and associated modules). So, when you tried `ProxyPassReverse` in `.htaccess` you didn't get a 500 Internal Server Error?! Otherwise, your second example (minus the `ProxyPassReverse` directive) would be what is required. (Incidentally, it would be `ProxyPassReverse /docs https://yyy/Public` - If you had access to the server config.)